# TypeError: this.io.in(...).emit is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, socket.io, jestjs, mocking

I mocked `in` and `emit` to test `this.io.in(room).emit(eventName, result);` using jest

`this.io.in(room).emit(eventName, result);`

`this.io.in(room)` is working well but I am not sure how to deal with `.emit(eventName, result);`

here is code

```
export interface ServerToClientEvents {
 
  [EVENTNAME]: (payload: payload[]) => void;
}
```

```
import {   BroadcastOperator, Server } from "socket.io";
import { ServerToClientEvents } from "../../common/Interfaces";

export class MockIo extends Server {
  hasEmitted = false;
  hasEmittedData: string[] = [];
  hasEmittedEventName: string | symbol = "";
  room: string | string[];

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  emit(event: string | symbol, ...args: any[]): boolean {
    this.hasEmitted = true;
    this.hasEmittedData = args;
    this.hasEmittedEventName = event;
    return true;
  }
 
   in(room: string | string[]): BroadcastOperator<ServerToClientEvents,any> {
     this.room = room;

      return this.emit.bind(this) ;
   }
  
}
```